# Finding bandwith used by individual computers in a Home network

Tags: windows, internet, router, connection

We have 3 computers connected wirelessly to Netgear WGR Router, which is connected to internet. Is there anyway I can find out the individual comp's bandwidth consumption at any point in time and a report of the total upload/download info per over a period of time. We are sharing an internet connection which has a download limit. I could not find that option in the router page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only router-based way that lets you monitor bandwidth usage per-computer (without headache) is using [IPTables bandwidth monitor](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/System/Networking/IPTables-Bandwidth-Monitor-47903.shtml) alongside [Tomato Firmware](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato), although this is a Linux approach. For Windows, it would be easier to install [NetStat Live](http://www.analogx.com/contents/download/network/nsl.htm) on each pc and monitor them individually.

Comment: but tomato firmware won't work with WGR614 Netgear router. I don't prefer to install NetStat in every system. Is there any other better firmware replacement for Netgear WGR 614 router?

Comment: the firmware approach was a linux way anyways, which is out of the question. I don't think a router-based monitoring solution is possible with your combination though. There are multiple ways to have all the data summarized and sent to your PC though, such as parsing the `netstat` command's values alongside each computer's MAC/IP and appending the data to a text file over a network share for you to see. This share could be on your PC to make things easier for viewing.