# Software to monitor internet usage

Tags: windows, internet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Desktop Internet traffic measurement  software](https://superuser.com/questions/13912/desktop-internet-traffic-measurement-software)

What good free software is there, that will run in the background and monitor how much is downloaded and uploaded?

If it would even report this data for several many computers (separate installs of course), so I could compare centrally - that would be neat. But less will do. :)

Please note, that just monitoring the network traffic is not enough, since that will include file transfers etc on the LAN.

Also note, that even though monitoring at your router/firewall would be a better solution, that is not always an option.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/14210/finding-bandwith-used-by-individual-computers-in-a-home-network and http://superuser.com/questions/13912/desktop-internet-traffic-measurement-software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [**NetMeter**](http://www.metal-machine.de/readerror/index.php?page=10) a lot. It is freeware.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/13912/desktop-internet-traffic-measurement-software) thread already the best option is [DU Meter](http://www.dumeter.com/) however it is not free as far as I am aware.

Alternatively you can look at using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Possibly not what your after but we wanted to monitor staff usage throughout the day and we utilised an old system and installed [IPCop](http://www.ipcop.org/) and we now keep an eye on the Proxy Logs.

This assumes firstly that you have a spare machine and secondly that it has at least two Network Adapters.